# How to find the reblog source from the Tumblr API

Tags: api, tumblr

Using Tumblr API v2, I have a list of photo posts in JSON using the /posts API call.

For each post I would like to know which user the post was reblogged from (if any), in the same way that Tumblr shows which user a post was reblogged from.

It is possible to get the source_url or source_title from the /posts reply but that is not the last reblogger - that appears to be the initial source.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reblog Info**

Reblog details are set to false by default when making requests to the Tumblr API. To enable them, send the following parameter, `?reblog_info=true`.

Example:

```
https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/pitchersandpoets.tumblr.com/posts?reblog_info=true
```

If reblogged, the response will contain the following:

```
"reblogged_from_id": "139318910829",
"reblogged_from_url": "http:\/\/travelswithzoe.tumblr.com\/post\/139318910829\/happy-valentines-day",
"reblogged_from_name": "travelswithzoe",
"reblogged_from_title": "Travels with Zo\u00eb",
"reblogged_from_uuid": "travelswithzoe.tumblr.com",
"reblogged_from_can_message": true,
"reblogged_root_id": "139318910829",
"reblogged_root_url": "http:\/\/travelswithzoe.tumblr.com\/post\/139318910829\/happy-valentines-day",
"reblogged_root_name": "travelswithzoe",
"reblogged_root_title": "Travels with Zo\u00eb",
"reblogged_root_uuid": "travelswithzoe.tumblr.com",
"reblogged_root_can_message": true
```